# Sql Bigquery - concat two columns into a new column

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to concat two columns shown below into one new column.

[image: A_Bill_ID B_BILL_ID]

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
CONCAT( A_Bill_ID , ' ', B_BILL_ID ) AS BILL_ID
FROM
`table.tmp_140222`
```

From this query, the result will be like this.

[image]

My problem is I want to concat only columns that don't have a similar value so that the new column value will not duplicate two times. From the above result, the ID is duplicated since both of the columns has the same value.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also include the starting data for your table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have already added the starting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement like this -

```
SELECT
case when A_Bill_ID = B_BILL_ID then a_bill_Id 
else CONCAT(A_Bill_ID , ' ', B_BILL_ID ) 
end AS BILL_ID
FROM `table.tmp_140222`
```

If there are Null values in the initial columns, you can use IFNULL or COALEASE to replace that with an empty string. But in this case, I would suggest using this without a delimiter or writing multiple 'when' statements to avoid tailing spaces in the final column -

```
SELECT
case when A_Bill_ID = B_BILL_ID then a_bill_Id 
else CONCAT(IFNULL(A_Bill_ID), ''), "", IFNULL(B_BILL_ID, ''))
end AS BILL_ID
FROM `table.tmp_140222`
```

Comment: for `case when A_Bill_ID = B_BILL_ID then a_bill_Id` is working good but `else CONCAT( A_Bill_ID , ' ', B_BILL_ID )` shows null value

Comment: It might happen when there are nulls in the initial columns. Updated answer to help with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select if (
    a_bill_id = b_bill_id, 
    a_bill_id, 
    concat(a_bill_id , ' ', b_bill_id )
  ) as bill_id
from your_table
```

> ... shows null value ....

```
select if (
    a_bill_id = b_bill_id or (a_bill_id = b_bill_id) is null,
    coalesce(a_bill_id, b_bill_id),
    concat(a_bill_id , ' ', b_bill_id )
  ) as bill_id
from your_table
```

Comment: for `a_bill_id = b_bill_id, a_bill_id` is working good but `concat(a_bill_id , ' ', b_bill_id` shows null value

Comment: see update to account null as a possible value in initial columns